# How to get the last element of a property in Javascript and return undefined if it doesn't exist

Tags: javascript

Most of the conditions of the online grader show that the tests pass except for returning undefined if the last property doesn't exist (it should return undefined if it doesn't exist).

The grader is telling me "TypeError: obj[key] is undefined" on that condition. Maybe this is easy but I don't get what I'm missing. Here's what I have so far.

```js
function getLastElementOfProperty(obj, key) {
  var length = obj[key].length
  if(length === 0){
      return undefined
  } 
  if(!Array.isArray(obj[key])){
      return undefined
  } 
  if(obj[key].length === 0){
      return undefined
  }
  else{
    return obj[key][length-1]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified code and added obj[key] validation

```
function getLastElementOfProperty(obj, key) {
  var returnVal;
  if( obj[key] ){
      var isArray = Array.isArray( obj[key] ),
          length = obj[key].length;
      if( isArray && length ){
        returnVal = obj[key][length - 1];
      }
  }
  return returnVal;
}
```

Comment: Why you first receive object length and only than check if it's array?

Comment: This is the correct answer, I'm going to try and work through it to fully get it myself. Thank you sir and to everyone for helping me out. I'll accept it in a few minutes when it'll let me.

Comment: @Justinas - You are right. let me update the code.  (note - length check may be just being extra cautious. it is probably not required if we are using isArray check..)

Answer (score 2):

`obj[key].length` will throw error when there is no such key, because it converts to `undefined.length`.

Change it to this code:

```
if (typeof obj[key] === 'undefined') {
    return undefined;
}
```

---

Optimize your *if*s:

```
if (typeof obj[key] !== 'undefined' && Array.isArray(obj[key]) && obj[key].length !== 0) {
    return obj[key][length-1];
}

return undefined;
```

Parser will not evaluate further conditions if finds *false* in if condition segment. E.g. if `typeof obj[key] === 'undefined'` than it will not check for `Array.isArray(obj[key])`

So basically your function can be converted to single-lined:

```
 function getLastElementOfProperty(obj, key) {
     return typeof obj[key] !== 'undefined' && Array.isArray(obj[key]) && obj[key].length !== 0
         ? obj[key][length-1]
         : undefined;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If `obj[key]` doesn't exist, then it is an error to try `obj[key].length`. Do a check before that to catch that case:

```
if (typeof obj[key] === "undefined")
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest code uses the fact that `array[-1]` is `undefined` and that having no return is the same as return undefined

testing for `obj &&` so if you pass in null/undefined etc as the object, it doesn't break

so it's just

```
function getLastElementOfProperty(obj, key) {
    if (obj && Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
        return obj[key][obj[key].length - 1];
    }
}
```

you could change the return statement to

```
return obj[key].slice(-1).pop() as well
```

If you want to be minimalist

```
function getLastElementOfProperty(obj, key) {
    return ((obj && Array.isArray(obj[key]) && obj[key].slice(-1)) || []).pop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with

```
 if (!(key in obj)) return "undefined";
```

before all other checks.